# How to merge two data frames with similar - but not identical - data?

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and have stumbled upon a problem. I currently have two data frames, one containing a list of items and their locations (list1) and one containing data pertaining to similar locations (list2)

e.g.

```
list1
name    start    end
a        1        50
b        51       74
c        89       201
d        300      543


list2
data   start     end
-1      1         80
0       85       224
1       256      603
```

I want to find out which of my items from list1 fall within the data observed for list2 to get an end product that would ideally look like:

```
list3
data   start     end    name
-1      1         80    a,b
0       85       224    c
1       256      603    d
```

So, in psuedocode I think I'm looking to do something like ...

```
for(each row in list2) {
     loop(each row in list2 {
         if((list1$start >= list2$start) & (list1$end <= list2$end)) {
                print (list1$name into new column)
              }
           }
       }
```

I've looked up different ways to do this, but so far struggling to make sense of how I specify the above in R.

I tried:

```
for(i in 1:dim(list2)[1]) {
  for(j in 1:dim(list1)[1]) {
    if((list1$start >= list2$start) & (list1$end <= list2$end)) {
      print(list1$name)
    }
  }
}
```

But that causes multiple of the same error:

```
In if ((list1$start >= list2$start) &  ... :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I think this is because the dataframe I'm using for the `if` statement isn't a `logical` vector of length 1, however, I'm not sure how else to perform the query.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Best wishes,
Natalie

Comment: Looks like you need `foverlaps` from `data.table`

Comment: One thing to note, the print out is a warning message, not an error message. That is, it will not break your program. However, your intuition about its meaning is correct. You can compare `if(1:5 > 0) print(1)` with `if(1 > 0) print(1)`.

Comment: Thanks so much @akrun, @lmo  Problem sorted thanks to `foverlaps` !!